# strcpy() and char

Tags: c, string, struct

I want to store a string to a char array inside a structure and when I access the char array I want the result to be displayed along with the value from the global variable errCode. When I access the errDesc member of the structure then I want the result to be "Error detected with error code 0xA0B0C0D0", but since using strcpy copies the string as it is I am getting a result "Error detected with error code %08lx" . Here is a sample code which replicates my issue:

```
int errCode = 0xA0B0C0D0;

void function(errpacket* ptr, int a, char* errString, ...);

typedef struct{
    int err;
    char errDesc;
}errpacket;

int main(){
    errpacket* a;
    void function(a, 10, "Error detected with error code %08lx", errCode);

    return 0;
}

void function(errpacket* ptr, int a, char* errString, ...){
    ptr->err = a;
    strcpy(&ptr->errDesc, errString);
}
```

If my implementation is incorrect, please suggest me a way to do what I intend to. Also please point out the mistakes in the above code.

Comment: `errDesc` is a single `char` at present - you need to make it a string.

Comment: `char` is for a single character. So it can't hold whaty you want to copy there.

Comment: You will have to use sprintf to create a new string with the error code inserted.

Comment: Thank you for the responses but can anyone please elaborate, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Remove the `void` in `void function(a, 10, "Error detected with error code %08lx", errCode);`. And compile with warning enabled and treat warnings as errors.

Comment: @Rookie_Coder2318: in addition of fix mentionned above, you need allocate memory if you use a as pointer `errpacket* a;` or use it as like this `errpacket a;` , check my answer below

Comment: will strcpy() add the intended value of the errCode variable to the string ? or is sprintf the only way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this fix:

```
#include <stdarg.h> //to be added for vsprintf use

int errCode = 0xA0B0C0D0;

void function(errpacket* ptr, int a, char* errString, ...);

typedef struct{
    int err;
    char *errDesc;
}errpacket;

int main(){
    errpacket a; //you need allocate memory if you use a pointer here
    void function(&a, 10, "Error detected with error code %08lx", errCode);

    return 0;
}

void function(errpacket* ptr, int a, char* errString, ...){
    ptr->err = a;
    ptr->errDesc = malloc(strlen(errString)+1);
    memset(ptr->errDesc, 0, strlen(errString)+1);
    /*if(ptr->errDesc != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(ptr->errDesc, errString);
    }*/
   // use like following if you want use a formatted string
   if(ptr->errDesc != NULL)
   {
        va_list args;
        va_start (args, errString);
        vsprintf (ptr->errDesc, errString, args);
        va_end (args);
   }
}
```

Comment: You should not cast the result of malloc in C, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @GovindParmar I think unwind is wrong, there are good arguments for the cast :-).

Comment: cast is not wrong, you can see http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html and https://www.quora.com/In-a-C-program-with-the-function-int-*-malloc-sizeof-int-what-does-int-*-mean

Comment: will strcpy() add the intended value of the errCode variable to the string ? or is sprintf the only way to do that ?

Comment: `vsprintf` only can do it, `sprintf` can do if and only if you the format is not a parameter of the function `function`

Answer (score 1):

1. you have to `typedef` the struct `errpacket` before declaration of `function(...)`
2. Variable `a` in function `main()` is only a pointer. You'll get a segmentation fault inside function if you try to write to an uninitialized pointer.

The member `errDesc` will only hold ONE char, not a string or char array.

Try this...

```
int errCode = 0xA0B0C0D0;

typedef struct {
    int err;
    char* errDesc;   
} errpacket;

void function (errpacket* ptr, int a, char* errString, ...);

int main () {
    errpacket a;
    function(&a, 10, "Error detected with error code %08lx", errCode);
    return 0;
}

void function (errpacket* ptr, int a, char* errString, ...) {
    ptr->err = a;
    ptr->errDesc = strdup( errString);
}
```

Comment: won't strdup() just duplicate the string as it is ? How about the sprintf() function , cause I want the value A0B0C0D0 added to the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a single `char` variable to hold an entire string.

What you *can* do is declare `errDesc` to be either an array of fixed length (if you know the maximum number of characters that an error description can contain), or a pointer that is allocated dynamically with `malloc` and later freed with `free`.

Array case:

```
#define MAX_ERR_STRING_SIZE 500

typedef struct 
{
    int err;
    char errDesc[MAX_ERR_STRING_SIZE];
} errpacket;

// You can now use strcpy() to copy to errpacket::errDesc assuming none of the error strings exceed MAX_ERR_STRING_SIZE
```

Dynamic memory:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int err;
    char *errDesc;
} errpacket;

// Take note of the new parameter: int errStringLength, 
void function(errpacket* ptr, int a, char* errString, int errStringLength, ...){
    ptr->err = a;
    ptr->errDesc = malloc((errStringLength + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if(ptr->errDesc == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy(&ptr->errDesc, errString);
}
```

After you are done using `ptr` you will need to call `free(ptr->errDesc);` to de-allocate the string.

Comment: will strcpy() add the intended value of the errCode variable to the string ? or is sprintf the only way to do that ?

Comment: @Rookie_Coder2318 You will need to use a `printf` family function to format a string containing numbers; `strcpy` can't do that

Comment: Yes, understood.  Thank you everyone !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really want a function with variable arguments, like printf. The solution below just expects the arguments you use in the end. Note that I do not use a user-supplied format string; that is considered a security risk. I also used [`snprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) (instead of the simple `sprintf`) in order to protect against error messages which are longer than the array size in the struct. The array size is a define so that it can be changed easily.

Specific fixes:

- Proper declaration order (define the struct type before it's used)
- Define an actual error packet object (and not just an uninitialized pointer to one)
- Provide actual memory in the error packet for the message
- Provide a print function for error packets
- Do not let the user code specify printf formats; print user supplied strings with a length protected `%s` format specifier.
- Do not use a variable argument function (whose excess arguments were not evaluated anyway); just declare the needed arguments explicitly.

.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int errCode = 0xA0B0C0D0;

#define MAX_ERRDESC_LEN 80 // avoid literals

typedef struct{
    int err;
    char errDesc[MAX_ERRDESC_LEN]; // provide actual space for the message
}errpacket;

void printErrPack(FILE *f, errpacket *ep){
    fprintf(f, "Error packet:\n");
    fprintf(f, "     err  = 0x%x:\n", ep->err);
    fprintf(f, "     desc = ->%s<-\n", ep->errDesc);
}

// Standard function with fixed argument count and types
void function(errpacket* ptr, int errNo, char* errString, int errCodeArg){
    ptr->err = errNo;

    // snprintf "prints" into a string
    snprintf(   ptr->errDesc,    // print destination
                MAX_ERRDESC_LEN, // max length, no buffer overflow
                "%s with error code %x", // do not use user string as format
                errString,       // user supplied string, printed via %s
                errCodeArg  );
}

int main(){
    errpacket a; // define an actual object, not a pointer

    // pass the address of the object a
    function(&a, 0xdead, "Error detected ", errCode);

    printErrPack(stdout, &a);
    return 0;
}
```